# <h1> inside or outside of <a>?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I want to use `h1` in `a` element. Which one is more correct?

```
<a href="#"><h1>Home</h1></a>
```

OR

```
<h1><a href="#">Home</a></h1>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [w3](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/Elements/A.html) describes the markup `A`:

> An anchor is a piece of text which marks the beginning and/or the end
> of a hypertext link.
>
> The text between the opening tag and the closing tag is either the
> start or destination (or both) of a link. Attributes of the anchor tag
> are as follows.

This means both are correct, and they don't have the exact same effect. So it depends on what you want to make a [hyperlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink), in case you surround the entire `<h1>` you need to put it as a parent. This will make the entire block clickable, including the space to the right:

```html
<a href="#"><h1 style="background-color: yellow">Anchor for entire title</h1></a>
```

In case you want to get only a specific part of the `<h1>` you only surround that part like this:

```html
<h1 style="background-color: yellow">Anchor only for <a href="#">this</a></h1>
```

Comment: Note that the first attempt will also make portions of the `<h1>` are clickable that may not contain text – if the heading contains multiple lines of text, for example.

Comment: @Mary Sure! It will make all the <h1> clickable, in this case we can't see it's 100% width because the background is white like the body background :p

Comment: @Marijan I edited the answer to take into account your comments.

Answer (score 6):

According to HTML5 [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) both are correct:

> The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables,
>   and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive
>   content within (e.g. buttons or other links).

Answer (score 2):

Both are fine.

It really depends if you want the whole heading to be a link or just the text in it.

(It's a bit odd to make the main heading for your page a link to the top of the page (or anywhere else for that matter) though.)